# Mongo group aggregation with priority of record

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform a MongoDB 3.6 aggregation and I can't figure out the right way.

The problem is following. After performing several aggregation steps I end up with result set like this:

```
[
  { _id: { month: 1, type: 'estimate' }, value: 50 },
  { _id: { month: 2, type: 'estimate' }, value: 40 },
  { _id: { month: 3, type: 'estimate' }, value: 35 },
  { _id: { month: 3, type: 'exact' }, value: 33.532 },
  { _id: { month: 4, type: 'estimate' }, value: 10 },
  { _id: { month: 4, type: 'exact' }, value: 11.244 },
]
```

It contains values grouped by month. Value for every month can be 'estimated' or 'exact'. Now I would like to reduce this result to achieve this:

```
[
  { _id: { month: 1 }, value: 50 },
  { _id: { month: 2 }, value: 40 },
  { _id: { month: 3 }, value: 33.532 },
  { _id: { month: 4 }, value: 11.244 },
]
```

Basically I want to use the value of type 'exact' whenever it's possible and only fallback to 'estimate' value in months where the 'exact' is not known.

Any help or tip will be greatly appreciated. I would like to perform that aggregation in the DB not on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by `type` and then take use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html) in next [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage which will give you `exact` if exists and `estimate` otherwise. Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { "_id.type": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$_id.month",
            value: { $first: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    }
])
```

Prints:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 50 }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 40 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 33.532 }
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : 11.244 }
```

So sorting by `type` is considered as prioritizing here since we know that lexically `exact` will be before `estimate`. You can also be more explicit and add extra field called `weight` (evaluated using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html)) operator and then sort by that weight:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { 
            weight: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$_id.type", "exact" ] }, 2, 1 ] } 
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "weight": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$_id.month",
            value: { $first: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    }
])
```